# Installing Sqlite3 Gem Error

Tags: macos, sqlite, rubygems

I'm getting the following error when trying to install the Sqlite3 gem on OS X Lion with XCode 4.2 installed:

```
$ gem install sqlite3
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... yes
checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... yes
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling backup.c
make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [backup.o] Error 1
```

Would linking to /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 be the only fix (seems a little hack-y)?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you do a `which gcc-4.2` and a `which llvm-gcc-4.2` please?

Comment: Alex: which gcc-4.2 yields nothing, and which llvm-gcc-4.2 results in  /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It would appear that XCode 4.2 doesn't install `gcc-4.2`, but instead `llvm-gcc-4.2`. Clearly Apple feels that [LLVM](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-llvm-gcc/_index.html) is mature enough to superseed GCC.

There are two options I can think of. You should be able to choose either and be OK.

1. Use [this GCC installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer).
2. Symlink LLVM using `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2`.

Comment: I figured that I'd have to symlink.  I considered installing GCC, but it seemed redundant with XCode already installed.  Thanks.